# Download a huge number of direct URLs

Tags: cloud-service, download-manager

I have a text file containing 121,000 direct URLs. I tried wget and aria2c but both were very slow. I need a site (paid or free) that downloads this list of files, compresses them and I download the huge file using a download manager.
Any advice is appreciated.